# Draw Cash Flow Diagram

Tags: diagrams

[image]

Hi i was wondering how to draw this diagram in latex.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You could have a look at the [tikz package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\foreach \X in {0,...,3}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (\X,-0.1) node[below]{$\X$} -- ++(0,0.6) node[above]{$1$};}
\draw[thick,-latex] (4.6,-0.1) node[below]{$n$} -- ++(0,0.6) node[above]{$1$};
\node at (3.8,0.4) {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DLichti is saying you could use Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5.4,0);
 \foreach \X in {0,...,3}
  {\draw[thick,-latex] (\X,-0.1) node[below]{$\X$} -- ++(0,0.6) node[above]{$1$};}
 \draw[thick,-latex] (4.6,-0.1) node[below]{$n-1$} -- ++(0,0.6) node[above]{$1$};
 \node at (3.8,0.4) {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]